# Ceramic made from alumina poisonous?

Tags: food-safety, ceramic

I was searching for ceramic knife and learned they can be made from Zirconia or Alumina.  Some cheap ones could be from the latter because material is cheaper.

Isn't Aluminum Oxide poisonous to human body?  I don't care much about the knife, but I do have a cheap manual cranking ceramic burr grinder for coffee.  Those single use pepper grinder also has ceramic.  Can't imagine they are made with quality in mind.

Should I worry?

Comment: Asking whether a specific compound is poisonous **is not** a question about nutrition or medical advice.

Comment: The Url is cooking.stackexchange, I thought that would make a food safety related question valid, no?

Comment: It is valid. Health advice generally is off topic. My comment was directed at the person who voted to close this and I was explaining that it is on topic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aluminium oxide is used in toothpaste (as an abrasive) and tablets (as an inactive filler). You'll get much more from these sources than from food preparation.

It's essentially insoluble in water as well, making it hard to absorb from food. Some other aluminium compounds are much more soluble especially given that the stomach is acidic, and are a cause for more concern.

For a (very) full review of the health science of aluminium compounds in general (including the oxide), see [*Human Health Risk Assessment for Aluminium, Aluminium Oxide, and Aluminium Hydroxide*, 
Krewski et al. J Toxicol Environ Health B Crit Rev. 2007; 10(Suppl 1): 1–269.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2782734/?report=classic)

Comment: Thanks, a very full review indeed.  I think the rumor I heard was about some aluminum compound used in food causing Alzheimer, but sounds like it's inconclusive.